# Bootstrap HTML input fields in one line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and am having a hard time having the following html inputs displayed in one like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">    
         <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Description"/>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Description"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have seen solutions that involve the use of html tables and I would like to know if there is another way aside from resorting to tables that one can achieve this. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us a drawing of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is now mobile first, which means that all element are assumed to be 100% without adjustment.  It's made for stacking on a device.  If you want to have your formatting stay on all devices you need to use col-xs-*.  You can also set the breakpoints of collapse manually at the bootstrap site.

Comment: Can you try using the inline class in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your HTML to this:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">  
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Description"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Description"/>
     </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://bootply.com/102620)

Answer (score 0):

read  bout [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Grid systems are used for creating page layouts through a series of rows and columns that house your content.
It uses classes to format its output.  The class `col-sm-8` means something 8 vertical columns.

The idea of using tables is quite old fashioned as it does not scale to use of multiple devices and does not resize well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input1" placeholder="Description">     
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input2" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

[In action](http://bootply.com/render/102607) (be sure to shrink it to a tiny screen to see it not collapse).

Answer (score 0):

From the [tutorial](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) itself, notice the `class="form-inline"`

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```